# Reducing an array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array that goes from '00:00:00' to '23:59:59', something like this ['00:00:00', '00:00:01' ... '23:59:59'].

I need to write a function to reduce the array length into n items but always keeping the first and the last element.

An example:

```
reduce_into($array, 3) -> ['00:00:00', '12:00:00', '23:59:59']
```

Note that the array must be "balanced", that means that when I reduce it into 3 elements it will return the first, the one in the middle and the last one.

Comment: Search google for "pie" and use the math you learned in grade school to cut it up into equally sized pieces. Or you could show us what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the code:

```
            function getnewarray($t,$i)
            {
                $newArr[0] = $t[0];
                $a = 1;
                $masterdivby = $divby = count($t) / ($i-1);
                $ni = $i-2;
                while($a <= $ni)
                    {
                    $newArr[$a] = $t[$divby];
                    $divby = $masterdivby + $divby;
                    $a++;   
                    }
                $newArr[$i]  = $t[count($t) - 1];   
                return $newArr;
            }
            ?>
```